# Question on Probability and Binomial

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, binomial-distribution

I'm doing a self-study. I am currently at part IV of the question. After several attempts, I still can't seem to figure out why $p = 0.75$ for part IV.

**QUESTION SHEET**

[image]

**ANSWER KEY**

[image]

Comment: All passengers can be boarded on the $i$-th flight if $X_i = 0$.

Comment: Please see my comment on your other question from today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that 0 people are bumped from a flight is 0.75. This is the same thing as the probability that everyone is able to board the flight. This is given in the table in the statement of the problem.